# Get Chrome console warning in new Visual Studio (VB) ASP.NET Web Application project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

On debugging JavaScript code in a ASP.NET Web Application using Google Chrome console, I get the following console warning :

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its >detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

The warning occurs every time when navigating from one local page to another.

This occures also in a brand new project (New Project > ASP.NET Web Application) without any extra code or scripts added.

I googled this and found the error occurs "when jQuery AJAX Call is used with async setting set to false".

I updated jquery with Package Manager Console to version 3.1.1, but 
the warning persists.

Just started learning JS I don't know if this warning could just be ignored.

My Visual Studio Version is:
 - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
 - Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
 - Microsoft .NET Framework
 - Version 4.6.01055
 - Installed Version: Community

Google Chrome Version:
 - Version 54.0.2840.99 m

I use the ASP.NET Development Server

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: somewhere you've got an ajax call with synchronous set to true (or async: false if you're using jQuery to make the call). Synchronous ajax calls are considered bad because it freezes the rest of the browser. To get rid of the warning, find the ajax call responsible and set it to asynchronous. It'll give your users a better experience as well.